# Normal distribution conditional on both deterministic and probabilistic statements

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

Let $w \sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ be multivariate normal and let $w_1,w_2$ be two non-overlapping sub-vectors of $w$ respectively. Then how would $w$ be distributed conditional on the following statements
$$S : = \{P_1w_1 = q_1,\quad P_2w_2 \sim N(q_2,\Omega)\}$$
in which $P_{1,2}$ are deterministic matrices and $q_{1,2}$ are deterministic vectors, $\Omega$ is the deterministic covariance matrix of $Pw_2$. Note that $P_{1,2}$ aren't assumed to be invertible or even square.

To give a quite generic example, let $w\in\Bbb R^6$, $w_1:=(w^{(1)}, w^{(2)})$, $w_2=(w^{(3)}, w^{(4)}, w^{(5)})$, and let the statements be: 
$$S:=\{w^{(1)}+w^{(2)}=2.5, \quad 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.5 & \sqrt{2}\\
-0.3 & 3.2 & 1.7
\end{bmatrix} w_2 \sim N(
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 \\ 0.3 
\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0\\
0 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix})\}$$
Then the question is to find $w\mid S$ or at least $\Bbb E(w\mid S)$. My guess is that $w\mid S$ is again normal, which is the case if the deterministic condition concerning $w_1$ is absent. Actually, my main problem is how to handle the deterministic part of $S$ or somewhow separate it from the probabilistic part.

---

EDIT: per @Did's comment, the non-deterministic part actually came from Black-Litterman's 1992 paper [*Global Portfolio Optimisation*](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/finread/black.pdf), in which the $\Omega$ measures how uncertain an investor is about his views on the returns of assets. In the Appendix part, the authors claimed that, with only the probabilistic condition, the conditional distribution of $w$ would be again a normal distribution.

Comment: There is no canonical definition of conditioning on the fact that a given random variable follows a given distribution. Please explain this part.

Comment: @Did Please see edit. I feel a bit weird too, but since it is an important feature in the original Black-Litterman paper, I think it must have some meaning.

Comment: Sorry but again, $$P(A\mid X=x)$$ is perfectly standard stuff but $$P(A\mid X=x,Y\sim Q)$$ for some event $A$, some random variables $X$ and $Y$, **and some probability distribution $Q$** is completely unorthodox. (And no, I shall not click on the link you suggest.)

Comment: @Did Yeah, I will certain trust your professional opinions on this subject than those of the financial people's :) Turns out to be another example where financial authors were trying to use something they were not sufficiently trained in (or at least, they were definitely under-trained in using appropriate mathematical notations, which caused a lot of confusion for math readers, sign).

Comment: In the present case, I would be in trouble if I had to guess what they are trying to achieve...