# Normal distribution conditional on a sub-affine space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

This is related to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2927757/191404). Now let's for the time being keep aside the unorthodox "probabilistic" statements and focus on the canonical deterministic part only. Suppose $w\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ is multivariate normal, and let $P$ be a known matrix, not necessarily square or invertible, and $q$ be a known vector such that $Pw=q$ has solutions, then what is the conditional distribution $w\mid \{Pw=q\}$ or $\Bbb E(w\mid Pw=q)$?

In [the original Black-Litterman paper](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~mkearns/finread/black.pdf) (p35) the authors claimed that the conditional is again normal and that
$$\Bbb E(w\mid Pw=q) = \mu + \Sigma P^T (P\Sigma P^T)^{-1} (q - P\mu)$$
and can be obtained by solving the following optimisation problem
$$
\begin{align}
\min \quad & (x - \mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\\
\text{s.t.}\quad & Px=q
\end{align}
$$
Is their claim valid? And would you mind elaborating a bit on why it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ and write $W = \mu + \Sigma^{1/2}Z$, where $\Sigma^{1/2}$ is the unique positive-definite square root of $\Sigma$ that commutes with $\Sigma$. Then $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$. Now define $A, B, Q$ as

$$
A = P\Sigma^{1/2}, \qquad
B = A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}, \qquad
Q = BA = A^{T}(AA^{T})^{-1}A.
$$

and notice that

1. $Q$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(A)^{\perp}$,
2. $I-Q$ is the orthogonal projection onto $\ker(A)$.

Now decomposing $Z$ into the sum of $Z_{\perp} = QZ$ and $Z_{||} = (I-Q)Z$, they are uncorrelated normal vectors and hence independent. From this, the conditioning equation $q = PW$ becomes

$$ q = PW = P\mu + A Z = P\mu + A Z_{\perp}. $$

Multiplying $B$ to both sides and using $Q^2 = Q$ (which follows from the fact that $Q$ is an orthogonal projection), we obtain

$$ B(q-P\mu) = BAZ_{\perp} = Q^2 Z = Q Z = Z_{\perp}$$

and hence the condition $PW = q$ determines the value of $Z_{\perp}$. So

\begin{align*}
(W \mid PW=q)
&\stackrel{d}{=} (\mu + \Sigma^{1/2}(Z_{\perp} + Z_{||}) \mid Z_{\perp} = B(q-P\mu)) \\
&\stackrel{d}{=} \mu + \Sigma^{1/2}B(q-P\mu) + \Sigma^{1/2}(1-Q)Z. \tag{*}
\end{align*}

The last line $\text{(*)}$ has several implications:

1. $\text{(*)}$ is an affine transformation of $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, I)$, hence it is again normal with

   $$ (W \mid PW=q) \sim \mathcal{N}( \mu + \Sigma^{1/2}B(q-P\mu), \Sigma^{1/2}(1-Q)\Sigma^{1/2}). $$

   Plugging all the definitions, mean of the conditional distribution $(W \mid PW=q)$ simplifies to

   \begin{align*}
   \mathbb{E}[W \mid PW=q]
   &= \mu + \Sigma^{1/2}B(q-P\mu) \\
   &= \mu + \Sigma P^{T} (P\Sigma P^{T})^{-1}(q-P\mu).
   \end{align*}
2. If we write $S = \Sigma^{1/2}B = \Sigma P^{T} (P\Sigma P^{T})^{-1}$, then $\text{(*)}$ can be simplified to a formula which involves only known variables:

   $$ (W \mid PW=q)
   \stackrel{d}{=} Sq + (I - SP) W. $$

Comment: Thanks but I cannot follow how you deduce $$Z_{\perp}  =\Sigma^{1/2}P^{T} (P \Sigma P^{T})^{-1} (q-P\mu)$$ from $$q = PW = P\mu + P\Sigma^{1/2} Z = P\mu + P\Sigma^{1/2} Z_{\perp}.$$

Comment: @Vim, I revamped my answer with more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: In the third statement of "notice that": $$\Sigma^{1/2}Q = Q\Sigma^{1/2}$$ did you implicitly assume that $P$ is invertible? Actually $P$ isn't necessarily invertible or even square. Following direct computation plugging in $A = P\Sigma^{1/2}$ I obtained $$\Sigma^{1/2} Q = \Sigma P^T(P\Sigma P^T)^{-1}P\Sigma^{1/2}$$ whereas $$Q\Sigma^{1/2} = \Sigma^{1/2} P^T(P\Sigma P^T)^{-1} P\Sigma.$$ I don't see how they can be equal without assuming $P$ is invertible.

Comment: However, it is evident that $$QA^T = A^T Q$$ or $$QA = AQ$$ since $Q$ is an orthogonal projection onto $\text{im}(A^T)$. So I suspect there might be a typo?

Comment: @Vim, It is so strange that I actually believed $\Sigma^{1/2}Q = Q\Sigma^{1/2}$ and inserted it into the answer, considering that it seems neither true nor ever used in my answer. Thank you for pointing out this.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and nice explanations! The rest is easy to follow through and very elucidative.

Comment: If interested, would you mind following up on this question? In the Black-Litterman paper, they not only provided the formula for $\Bbb E(W\mid PW=q)$ but also claimed that $W\mid PW = q+\epsilon,\,\epsilon\sim N(0, \Omega)$ is normal and claimed that $$\Bbb E(W\mid PW = q+\epsilon) = (\Sigma^{-1}+P^T\Omega^{-1}P )^{-1}(\Sigma^{-1}\mu + P^T\Omega^{-1} q)$$ Now, according to user Did (also on MSE), there's no orthodox way to define a conditional distribution on the statement that a r.v. follows a certain distribution...

Comment: ... may I ask if you also agree that $\Bbb E(W\mid PW=q+\epsilon)$ actually makes no sense, or if the explicit expression $$(\Sigma^{-1}+P^T\Omega^{-1}P )^{-1}(\Sigma^{-1}\mu + P^T\Omega^{-1} q)$$ somehow rings the bell for you? I suspect BL used some confusing notations but meant otherwise. Thank you very much!

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Turns out the authors should have actually meant a Bayesian posterior updating approach but totally left me confused with their sloppy notations.